# Correção de métodos Service Spring Boot

Tags: java, mvc, spring-boot

Boa noite, estou criando um API com spring baseada em um curso. Porém possui alguns métodos que possivelmente estão depreciados na versão que eu estou utilizando(2.2.6) versão do curso(1.5.10).

Preciso aplicar a atualização nos seguintes:

**Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional to User**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**The constructor PageRequest(int, int) is undefined**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue minha classe **UserServiceImpl:**

```
package com.br.helpdesk.helpdesk.api.service.impl;

import com.br.helpdesk.helpdesk.api.entity.User;
import com.br.helpdesk.helpdesk.api.repository.UserRepository;
import com.br.helpdesk.helpdesk.api.service.UserService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        return this.userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    @Override
    public User createOrUpdate(User user) {
        return this.userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(String id) {
        return this.userRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String id) {
        this.userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<User> findAll(int page, int count) {
        Pageable pages = new PageRequest(page, count)
        return null;
    }

}
```

Classe **User**:

```
package com.br.helpdesk.helpdesk.api.entity;

import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import com.br.helpdesk.helpdesk.api.enums.ProfileEnum;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class User {

    @Id
    private String Id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @NotBlank(message = "Email required")
    @Email(message = "Email invalido")
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(message = "Passwor required")
    @Size(min = 6)
    private String password;

    private ProfileEnum profile;

    public String getId() {
        return this.Id;
    }

    public void setId(String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public ProfileEnum getProfile() {
        return this.profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(ProfileEnum profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }

}
```

Por ultimo **UserService**:

```
package com.br.helpdesk.helpdesk.api.service;
import com.br.helpdesk.helpdesk.api.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
public interface UserService {
    User findByEmail(String email);
    User createOrUpdate(User user);
    User findById(String id);
    void delete(String id);
    Page<User> findAll(int page, int count);
}
```

Alguém já passou por isso e pode me ajudar?

Comment: Sua pergunta até parece ser legal. Mas não entendi exatamente o que é que você está perguntando. Quanto ao `findById` seria só mudar o retorno do método para `Optional<User>`. Quanto ao `PageRequest`, seria usar `PageRequest.of(page, count)`.